# C++: Pointers, finding address of its target?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but I'm unable to find it.

Basically, I'm looking at these variables:

```
unsigned short* bufferName = 0;
unsigned short* pBuffer = 0;
bufferName = new unsigned short[6400];
pBuffer = bufferName;
cout << &bufferName << &pBuffer
```

This set up enables reading in 6400 pixels (each = 2 bytes) into `bufferName`. The variable `pBuffer` is used to track within the block of `bufferName`'s memory.

The `cout` statement on line 5 prints the address of each. But as soon as I increment: `pBuffer`, how can I find the new address that it is pointing to?

Many thanks for your patience and time. I know this post is very short on what I'm done, but I'm trying to intentionally keep it brief.

Comment: If you increment it it should should be accessible with `&pBuffer`.

Comment: Your brevity is appreciated :-).

Comment: But the question is funny, I am not sure whether I understand it. It's akin to "I have an integer `i`. But as soon as I increment it, how can I find its new value?". The value is *in the variable.* That is true for pointers as well as other variables which hold values. (An address is the value held by a pointer. 4 or 8 bytes.).

Comment: A more interesting question would be "I have a pointer which points somewhere into an array" (in your example, `pBuffer`); "how can I find the start of that array?" The answer is, in C and C++, you can't (from `pBuffer` alone). You must keep the address in another variable (here: `bufferName` (what a funny name! `bufferName` is not a name, it's a buffer proper!) or keep track of the offset/index).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*But as soon as I increment: pBuffer, how can I find the new address that it is pointing to?*

The address pointed to by a pointer is its value.

So

```
cout << pBuffer;
```

will output the address pointed to.

```
cout << * pBuffer
```

will output the value in the address pointed to ( called 'dereferencing' )

```
cout << &pBuffer
```

will output the address of the pointer itself ( never changes )

Comment: Apologies, it took me awhile to get back to this. All the answers are very informative; I think the main problem (for me) was just over thinking.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable that stores the address of some other variable by defination.

So it works directly with addresses unlike other variables that work with values.

So if you want to see the location being pointed by a pointer you should simply show its value(pointer's value) it will be the address of the pointed location.
Eg

```
cout<< pbuffer ;
```

But if you will do cout<<&pbuffer; then it will show the address of the pointer rather than showing the address being pointed by it

Suppose a variable 'A' which is an integer pointer let it is at memory '5669' but it is set to point to some other variable 'B' which is at '7526'.

Here comes the difference in the output:-

```
cout<< A << endl;

cout<<&A;
```

Output::

```
7526
5669
```

Answer (score 0):

`bufferName` and `pBuffer` are already pointers.

If you want to know the address `pBuffer` is pointing to, you just have to print it :

```
std::cout << pBuffer;
```

If you want to modify the value it references, you have to dereference it :

```
*pBuffer = 2;
```

Its address will never change `&pBuffer`.

Here is your example remastered, you will see an increment of 2 (because of the size of unsigned short) in the new address of `pBuffer` after a post incrementation :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned short* bufferName = 0;
    unsigned short* pBuffer = 0;
    bufferName = new unsigned short[6400];
    pBuffer = bufferName;
    std::cout << "Address of bufferName " << bufferName << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of pBuffer " << pBuffer << std::endl;
    pBuffer++;
    std::cout << "New address of pBuffer " << pBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

Example output :

```
Address of bufferName 0x87a750
Address of pBuffer 0x87a750
New address of pBuffer 0x87a752
```

View on C++Shell : http://cpp.sh/2mjy